# Psql command connect in db without password

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker

Good morning everyone, I have a "problem" connecting to the postgresql database, I'm doing some tests on an AWS server running postgres via docker.
So I configured it in a simple way with the standard postgres docker image, and configured the users for testing and tried to connect, via PgAdmin it asks for the users' password, however, if I execute the command in the `psql` terminal it connects to database directly in the user past without asking for the password, and allows you to make changes.
I'm new when it comes to docker, do I have to do any specific configuration?

Example of the command I used:
`psql -h host -p 5432 -d bankname -U test_fvg`

Regardless of whether the user is superuser or not, it connects automatically without asking for the password via cmd, but in pgadmin it always asks for the password.
Command output:

`psql -h host -p 5432 -d bankname -U test_fvg`

`psql (16.0)`

`WARNING: Console code page (850) differs from Windows code page (1252)`

```
      `8-bit characters may not work correctly. See page`
     `psql reference "Notes for Windows users" for details.`
```

`Type "help" for help.`

`bankname=# \q`

I have already changed the passwords, but in any case it continues to connect without anything being requested, but in the same way in pgAdmin it still requests the password

Others informations requested:

- Yes, i'm just put `-h host` for anonymization
- I run the psql command on Windows machine, not in AWS
- Yes, pgAdmin ask for password when i select the AWS configured server in servers list

Comment: The Portuguese StackOverflow Web site is https://pt.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: More information needed. Add information requested as text update to your question text 1) Are you running the `psql` on the AWS server or somewhere else? 2) Are you sure when you are using pgAdmin4 you are connecting to same server? 3) Where is pgAdmin asking for the password, when it loads, when you select a server or somewhere else?

Comment: Are you really using `-h host`, or is that an anonymization?

Comment: I'm updated the requests, sorry for not including all the information